# restore ntbackup on server 2003 share

Tags: windows-server-2003, backup, windows-xp, network-share

i have access to a share on a windows 2003 server... i can create files and folders in this folder... i used ntbackup to backup my files from this share, but when i delete/rename my folder and try to restore all that is restored is the folders the files are not restored... although i can restore the files to a local location

thanks

Answer (score 1):

when you deleted the folder and created a new one, did you do this from your PC or from the Server.

Remember, Share permissions are not the same as NTFS file permissions.
If you deleted the folder and created a new one, the new one inherits the share persmissions of the share, until you go in and change them.

To create/restore files, the folder you created needs write permissions

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/107391

Comment: +1 I was typing an almost identical answer when yours popped up.

Comment: Sorry John. Got to hate fast typers, LOL

Comment: i said i can create files and folders... the ntbackup also restores the folders after i delete them... just not the files... "Reason: Access is denied" why i am just not sure why i have permission to create files and folders but ntbackup claims it cannot